Do Electron-Withdrawing-Groups give an hypsochromic shift or a bathochromic one? and why?
I'm not familiar with this topic,but i know that bathochromic shifts occur when the energy gap between energy levels of the substituted molecule, are lower than the unsubstituted one;viceversa hypsochromic shift when the gap is bigger. If i have,for example,nitrobenzene,what shift will occur?
Can someone tell me more about this?
Thanks in advance.

You mean benzene versus nitrobenzene?

@MathewMahindaratne yes

Moving to more electron-donating substituents gives the bathochromic shift in alizarin, and it is quite visible.
When alizarin is deprotonated, it shifts from a yellow color in strongly acidic solution through reds/purples in more neutral solution to blue in strong base, as shown in the picture below from Ref. 1.

As shown in the structural formulas, the color shift correlates with the conversion of the hydroxyl groups to more strongly electron-donating $\ce{O^-}$ functions. To see that the effect is indeed bathochromic, we can take the complements of the observed colors as indications of the most strongly absorbed optical wavelength, and we see that this complement ranges from blue (acid, hydroxyl groups) to yellow or orange (base, $\ce{O^-}$). The observed effect matches the spectrochemical series wherein pi donor ligands lower the splitting between orbitals and pi-acceptor ligands raise it.
Incidentally, the color sequence reported above for alizarin also occurs in temper colors on steel, where the bathochromic effect comes from a thicker oxide layer shifting the principal absorption by interference to longer wavelengths.
Reference

Priyadarshi, Ruchir & Ezati, Parya & Rhim, Jong-Whan. (2021). "Recent Advances in Intelligent Food Packaging Applications Using Natural Food Colorants". ACS Food Science & Technology. XXXX. 10.1021/acsfoodscitech.0c00039.

